# How to delete a string in an excel cell by comparing the value in another cell of the same excel

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario I tried:

[This is the look and feel of my macro project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my0Am.png)

From the above image , Range (F4) string value is "GREEN" then i do not want to see Action for next week in range Range (G4) for this i used the below script , But it went in vain as I am not able to see the character getting deleted.

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR").Cells(I, 6).Value = "GREEN" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR").Range("G4").Characters(WorksheetFunction.Find("Action Plan for next Week:", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR").Range("G4").Value, 1), Len("Action Plan for next Week:")).Delete
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Your code will delete the string "Action Plan for next Week:" alone from the G4 cell and retains the remaining string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there was a lot wrong with your code but certainly the call to the [WorksheetFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) object's [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) could be replaced with VBA's native [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). A couple of vars to hold the string and the starting position simplify matters. A [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) takes the parent worksheet reference out to a single localized position.

```
Dim sp As Long, ln As Long, i As Long, str As String

i = 4
str = "Action Plan for next Week:" & Chr(10)
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR")
    If UCase(.Cells(i, 6).Value2) = "GREEN" Then
        sp = InStr(1, .Range("G4").Value, str, vbTextCompare)
        .Range("G4").Characters(Start:=sp, Length:=Len(str)).Delete
    End If
End With
```

I've added a line feed character onto the tail end of the string so that you wouldn't be left with a blank line.

---

<sub>The [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) performs a case-senstive search; the [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3)'s substring location is **not** case sensitive.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have posted will delete the string "Action Plan for next Week:" alone from the G4 cell and retains the remaining string.

Tested code - substituted I as 4 to match F4

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR").Cells(I, 6).Value = "GREEN" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR").Range("G4").Characters(WorksheetFunction.Find("Action Plan for next Week:", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR").Range("G4").Value, 1), Len("Action Plan for next Week:")).Delete
End If
```

but if you want to remove whatever values below it has (from the image Print Solution.. , Test strategy ..  Enablement test scenario .. ) then you can use the below code

```
I = 4
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR").Cells(I, 6).Value = "GREEN" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR").Range("G4").Characters(WorksheetFunction.Find("Action Plan for next Week:", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FortnightlyWSR").Range("G4").Value, 1)).Delete
End If
```